# Eclipse pydev: automatically save file when running program

Tags: eclipse, pydev

It used to be that when I made changes to my .py file in Eclipse, then the changes would be automatically saved when I then ran the program in debug mode. I liked this since it meant that what it was debugging was the same as what I was looking at. Now it no longer does that, which means that's it's actually running an old version, unless I manually save the file first. The first time I ran the program, Eclipse asked me whether I always wanted any changes to be saved when the program was run, and I answered yes. I don't know why it doesn't do it anymore or how to get it back.

This seems to have happened after I started using Mercurial TortoiseHg with BitBucket. As part of that, I did move some files around, but everything is back and named the same as before.

Of course, I can just do change, save, run, but I'd rather not have to remember the extra save step.

Edit: Actually it's a bigger problem. It also shifts my breakpoints. In regular edit mode, I 1) set a break point and Save. 2) Add a new line above the breakpoint. Everything looks fine. 3) Save. Now the first breakpoint shifts position.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit about the breakpoint thing. When you add a newline above a breakpoint, the breakpoint will move down as it should. What exactly happens to the breakpoint when you save the file (it should be nothing)?

Comment: If the first breakpoint is by the line "print 'hello'" then, after the second save, it's no longer by this line. It appears to have moved up in reference to the line. So, yes, I suppose it's actually not moving, but should be.

Comment: Something seems badly messed up in saving. Have you tried removing the TortoiseHg to see if these problems go away? Have you considered also MercurialEclipse instead? I use this without trouble.

Comment: Removing TortoiseHg didn't work. The problem was still there. Instead I "fixed" the problem by creating a new Eclipse project and copying my files into it. Everything works fine. I will try TortoiseHg again, I think, and see how that works out the second time. Not sure that's what caused the problem.

Comment: Alright, adde TortoiseHg to my new project. Everything works fine again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it seems that you're always opening the file as an external file and not a file within your workspace (the fact that breakpoints don't get updated is the major clue here).

You can check if this is what happening from the title that's shown in Eclipse (if it's a full filesystem path and not relative path considering your workspace location, this is what's probably happening).

How are you opening the file you're running? Are you opening it from the PyDev package explorer or dragging from the filesystem? (also, it'd be interesting knowing which eclipse/pydev/tortoise versions are you using)

Comment: I no longer have the old project with the mistake since I "fixed" the problem by making a new project and copying my files in. But, yes, it could have gotten out of sync because I had renamed folders, etc. as part of setting up TortoiseHg. Also, at one point my file was opened in notepad by mistake. And, yes, at some point the file name (in Explorer) contained the full path, but that somehow went away and then it was just the name itself. I'm pretty sure I opened the file by going to File -> Open file in Eclipse.

Comment: Man, maybe the problem could have gone away had I just opened it again via the PyDev Package Explorer. (I'm afraid to try whether I can recreate the problem with "Open File".)

Comment: Just to note, PyDev itself had a bug (on older versions) which made it open the files as external files when it shouldn't sometimes (this is fixed in latest versions, but if you're still on an old version, it may be nice updating it).

Answer (score 3):

Look at your Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching, you probably have "Never" set for Save Required Dirty Editors before launching.

Comment: Nope. It's set to "Always". I also have a checkmark in "Build (if required) before launching" (seems like it might be relevant). I will now add an edit to my question because the problem also affects my breakpoints jumping around.